# What's the easiest way to add Java servlets to a WAMP configured machine?

Tags: java, php, apache, servlets, wamp

I have WAMP installed on my local machine and am looking to serve up charts using jFree's Eastwood charting, which requires me to use servlets. So basically I will insert images with src tags that have URLs pointing to my servlet on the same machine.

What's the easiest way to enable servlets on the same machine? Do I need to install a servlet server on a different port? Or is there a way to integrate it into WAMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of choices.

The easiest is to get a Web container such as Tomcat or Jetty and run it on a different port (by default it's usually 8080).

A Web container can be integrated into Apache and this tends to be what happens in production sites. See [Tomcat-Apache HOWTO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.2-doc/tomcat-apache-howto.html#work_together) or [Apache 2 with Tomcat 6: How to Configure](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/ApachePlusTomcat_HowTo.html). It's probably overkill for a local install.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a stupid simple way to setup Tomcat or Jetty, and why would I want one over the other? I am looking for something as stupid simple as WAMP, if it exists for this.

Comment: By the way, I am on Windows 7, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: Wow, done. Wow, very amazing how easy that was! Have it all running in under 10 minutes :)

Comment: @Rhubarb Jetty vs Tomcat, it's really six of one, half a dozen of the other. Either will do although I tend to prefer Jetty.

Comment: @Rhubarb I have the same problem and no clue how to get it done in 10 mins? What steps did you take to use tomcat and wamp?